# Como transferir um arquivo(db) do Android para o PC utilizando Delphi(Firemonkey)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, pascal, usb

Estou utilizando o Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 para programação Android, adjunto do Firemonkey(FMX), necessito criar um código que seja possível dentro do App no android consiga transferir um arquivo no caso o Banco de Dados para o PC via USB, sem utilização de internet que é o propósito.

Já tentei usar ShellExecute porém android é android e Windows é windows isso ficou aparente, WinExec também.

Intent não iria funcionar pois é mais utilizado pelo FileProvider em URL e URI

Tenho ciência que tem como utilizar o ADB(Android Debug Bridge) para fazer isso via CMD, mas não sei como fazer isso, já tentei utilizar plugins do Java mas parece que no Delphi Tokyo ou o próprio FMX é incompatível com algumas classes do Android Object Pascal Wrapper( biblioteca FMX Express de Android SDK's compilados para o java to pas).

Segue código que eu pensei se usar o cmd com o ADB :

```
procedure TfrmSync.lblUsbClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   command : string;
   val     : TValidate;
begin
    val := TValidate.Create;
    Command := 'C:\Users\Geovani\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe pull '+TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'pedidos.db')+' '+'C:\Users\Geovani\Desktop\Gi\TESTE BANCO';
    val.USB(Command);
end;
```

---

A procedure USB(Cmd) por enquanto não tem nada relevante pois não sei como fazer isso, não tenho ideia e procurei muito só acho na maioria via Socket por ClientSide e ServerSide, o que seria inviável pra mim pois estava a procura de Offline e simples como uma trasnferência.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Olá! Primeiramente existem algumas lacunas que precisam ser respondidas. 
1) Onde ficará a aplicação (Windows, Android)?
2) Quando uma conexão USB ocorre, se permitido através do Android será naturalmente gerada uma "unidade", exemplo "E:", "F:" ou qualquer outra letra disponível, no Windows. E este for seu caso, acho que seria o melhor caminho para você transferir informações entre os sistemas.

Comment: 1) Android , 2) Mas vc diz isso a princípio de utilizar o ADB ou os próprios comandos CMD/DOS mesmo ?